# Pasting array to worksheet taking a long time

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code

```
Set Destination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Catalogue").Range("a4")
Application.StatusBar = "Please be patient we are pasting the data into the  list"
With Destination
    .Resize(UBound(default_layout, 1), UBound(default_layout, 2)).Value = default_layout
End With
```

default_layout is a 2D array approx 65000 x 29

I can churn and manipulate the data in several ways in about 5 seconds but getting it back into a work book takes approx 90 seconds??

Screen Updating and calculations are both set to off

Any idea how to speed this one up

Comment: disable events and switch calculation to manual.

Comment: Spot on!  thanks Jeeped